# Fetch RSS value using Nordic NRF24L01 module and RadioHead library

Tags: signal, nrf24l01, field-strength

RadioHead provides a `lastRssi()` function (http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRHGenericDriver.html#ab04f2ca335d89f5fac1d213c0aea9da2) to fetch the received signal strength.

I tried using this but the value always shows up as zero. I also tried changing the TransmitPower (http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__NRF24.html#abf31686ee994851a27d6a9d7dc51771f), however, it still shows up as zero. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this and would like to get back here.

NRF24 module does not have an RSSI unfortunately. NRF51822 does.